# Perl splits string incorrectly when loaded from file

Tags: string, windows, perl, file

I am probably missing out on something becauseI started Perl today, so please excuse me if it's something very obvious.

I would like to load string from a file and then split it character by character.
I have done the following

```
use strict;    
open my $fh, "<", "hello.txt" || die "Cannot open file!\n";

my $data = do { local $/ ; <$fh>};
print $data;

print  join( ', ',(split( //, $data)));

close $fh;
```

When I execute this script the first print statement prints $data without problem, however the second print prints only the join string.

```
Hello, world!
,
```

I am running on Windows 7 machine with Strawberry Perl, I don't have access to Unix/Linux machine at the moment so I could not test it elsewhere.

Comment: Tip: Since you read the file inside a block, open it there, too. That nicely contains (scopes) the `$fh` to just that block, and pulls all related code together.  So, `my $data = do { local $/; open my $fh ...; <$fh> };`  The file _is_ closed as the code exits the block and `$fh` ceases to exist.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but it's possible to use eg VMware Player and an Ubuntu image to run Linux while still otherwise in Windows.

Comment: I would but I'm bit lazy setting it up right now:).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably an issue with the carriage return character `"\r"` – Windows line endings are `\r\n`, and a `\r` on its own moves back to the start of the line, overwriting what you have already written.

You could `chomp $data` first to remove the line ending, though this will only remove the last line ending.

You can also have Perl convert the Windows `\r\n` line endings to Unix `\n` line endings when reading in the file, by applying the `:crlf` IO layer:

```
open my $fh, "<:crlf", "hello.txt" or die "Cannot open file!\n";
```

(Note that it must be `open … or die …` or `open(…) || die …` but not `open … || die …`, because of operator precedence rules.)

Comment: :crlf doen't change anything the problem persist.